# CORS policy error not working on domain in ASP.NET Web API and React js front end

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, cors

I created an ASP.NET Web API which generates the pdf. It's running on Swagger and I got no error no cors policy error I mean my API is working fine in Swagger.

But after deploying it to plesk, I got this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZbr3.png)

My API project is working fine on localhost, but it's not working on frontend

I have tried everything every CORS policy... I tried `.WithOrigin("*")` and also try with specific like `https://doctor.echowhite.com`

Comment: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: asp.net api ? Or asp.net core ? And please share your cors settings, then we can help you.

Comment: builder.Services.AddControllers(options => options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new DateTimeModelBinderProvider()));
builder.Services.AddCors(p => p.AddPolicy("corsapp", builder => { builder.WithOrigins("*").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().WithExposedHeaders("Content-Disposition", "Content-Type"); }));
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("corsapp");

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.